# How To Block Specific User Agent Android Dalvik

Tags: string, apache, .htaccess, bots, user-agent

I want to block spesific user agent android in .htaccess LIKE

```
"Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 9; POCOPHONE F1 MIUI/V10.3.6.0.PEJMIXM)"
```

I try this not working

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent 
"Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 9; POCOPHONE F1 MIUI/V10.3.6.0.PEJMIXM)" bad_user
Deny from env=bad_user
```

but this works not specific

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "POCOPHONE" bad_user
Deny from env=bad_user
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument in [SetEnvIf](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) Directive is  a [regular expression](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/glossary.html#regex), so you need to escape any [special character](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Regular_expressions_1__Special_characters.html) in your string:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Dalvik/2\.1\.0 \(Linux; U; Android 9; POCOPHONE F1 MIUI/V10\.3\.6\.0\.PEJMIXM\)" bad_user
Deny from env=bad_user
```

Comment: i try this, but not working. thankyou for your answer